# Gradle release build failed with Gradle 3.3

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I cant deal with gradle build for several hours.
It all ok on debug build but release just not building.

Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 24 declared in library [Wear App sub-manifest] /home/NAME/BOOM/app/build/generated/manifests/microapk/staging/AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="" to force usage

I understand suggestion, but not understand how to use it and where.

Also, I cant find declared minSdkVersion 24 anywhere in my app modules.

Comment: Are you using Wear App lib?

Comment: @Stefan I am using Wear module

Comment: You have a problem of conflicting minSdkVersion with a module/library called staging

Comment: are you using gradle as build tool ?

Comment: It's probably Android Studio unsolved issue. Downgrade of Android Studio might be solution, but I don't know if it settle you.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232834

Comment: @MatPag I know that

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes

Comment: if @Mij is right the only thing you can do for now is reverting android gradle plugin back to 2.2.3 until it's fixed (without downgrading AS)

Comment: @Mij, yap, downgrade to 2.2.3 works

Comment: @Mij, post it as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably Android Studio unsolved issue.

For now downgrade of Android Studio is a solution, 
but I don't know if it fits you.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232834